# @media section styles are not being applied; other @media sections working

Tags: html, css, screen, media

I'm editing a pre-existing stylesheet. It currently has @media sections for 0-319px and for 320-479px, as well as a few others for larger screens. I'm trying to add iphone-specific styles. However, my iphone's screen is 320px, but I don't want to put iphone styles in the 320-479 section, because I only want it to be applied to the iphone, not tablets. So, I added a new section to the end of my stylesheet that goes up to 329px, and put the specific styles in there, but they are not being recognized.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 319px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        position: relative !important;
        margin-top: 1px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0 0 24px 25px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #de0662;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        position: relative !important;
        margin-top: 1px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 90px;
        padding: 0 0 24px 25px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #de0662;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 329px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        min-height: 115px;
    }

    .carousel-slide-dialog p {
        max-width: 235px;
    }
}
```

When I look at the stylesheet in dev tools, my new section is there, so it's not a cache issue. But it's not being applied (I have my window size at 323px).

Comment: did you add this meta tag ? 

    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Comment: no, but right now i'm still testing on my desktop. I've shrunk the screen to 323px, and the styles from @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) are being applied

Answer (score 0):

Your first two media queries are mostly the same, with the exception of the min-height attribute in 320-479. Also, `@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 319px)` is the essentially the same thing as just `@media screen and (max-width: 319px)`

Why don't you refactor the media queries so that there are not overlapping media queries, like this:

```
@media screen {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        position: relative !important;
        margin-top: 1px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0 0 24px 25px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #de0662;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 319px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        min-height: initial;
    }
    .carousel-slide-dialog p {
        max-width: initial;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 329px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        min-height: 115px;
    }

    .carousel-slide-dialog p {
        max-width: 235px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 330px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .carousel-slide-dialog {
        min-height: 90px;
    }
    .carousel-slide-dialog p {
        max-width: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid altering the css too much because someone else made them, and the first two sections have much more than just .carousel-slide-dialog in them, I only included the relevant lines. I really don't want to change the first two sections since I'm not the one who made them

Comment: Since you do not want to alter the CSS very much, I still recommend dealing with the media queries overlapping issue. You don't have to shuffle around any of the pre-written CSS but add the styling that you would like to your new query and change the widths that the queries are capturing -- changing widths is much easier than moving many lines of code around.